# Click on through all links in a page with a 5-second delay using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create a pre-cache system for my site.
So far I created a simple HTML page and I used the JavaScript to click on links every 5 seconds.
The problem I face is with loops, so I can't go through links with any method, and every 5 seconds it clicks the same first link.
I tried so many ways (different conditions and loop) but they didn't work Also, I search for it and the result that I found did not help me.
It's safe to say that I'm not advanced in using js so I need some help.
Codes That I have

```js
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('test').click();
}, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: yekan;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  direction: rtl;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>pre-Cache</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <a class="click" id="test" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">1</a>
  <a class="click" id="test" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">2</a>
  <a class="click" id="test" href="https://yahoo.com/" target="_blank">3</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: You can only have 1 item with the same ID, if you want all links you should use something like [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).

Comment: @Reyno Hi, I tried the "getElementsByTagName" and it only works for the first link (I couldn't figure out a way to make the if loop work as Mohit Kumar did). And using duplicate class is not a standard way to code but look at this example it definitely works!
https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso/x3hdaf1d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `class` instead of `id`

```
 const clickInterval = setInterval(function () {
   const el= document.querySelector('.click:not(.clicked)');
   if(el){
     el.classList.add('clicked');
     el.click()
  }else{
     clearInterval(clickInterval);
  }    
},5000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it did the trick but I have a question. How it understands to stop and it won't loop the process since I don't see any break or out of loop code?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting unique id's for your a elements:

```
<a class="click" id="test1" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">1</a>
<a class="click" id="test2" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">2</a>
<a class="click" id="test3" href="https://yahoo.com/" target="_blank">3</a>
```

Then try something like this:

```
<script>
var position = 1;
setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('test' + position).click();
        position++;
        if(position>3){
            position = 1; 
        }
    },5000);
 
</script>
```

This is just an idea. I didn't test it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help I test it but it didn't work. But @Mohit Kumar solution did work

Comment: Yes, his solution is really neat